# How to monitor users who use dropbear ssh tunneling?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, dropbear

With OpenSSH in my Debian server, I can see who is using ssh tunneling using either nethogs or top command. When I change from openssh to dropbear I can't monitor user again. In nethogs or top command it only shows the root user. How to see if other user is using ssh tunneling?